# const pointer members and operator=

Tags: c++

```
class Point {
public:
    Point(int x, int y) : { x = new int(x); y = new int(y) }
    ...
    ...
    Point& operator=(const Point& other) {
        if(this!=&other){
            delete x;
            delete y;
            x = new int(*other.x);
            y = new int(*other.y);
        }
        return *this;
    }
private:
    const int* x;
    const int* y;
}
```

Will this implementation of operator= work even if x and y of this were already initialized? does deleting a const pointer allow us to reassign it?

Comment: Why do you hold pointers in the first place?

Comment: A question from one of the previous exams of my course

Comment: That's not a const pointer, but a pointer to a const.

Comment: Oh. How do you declare a const pointer then?

Comment: Like this: `int* const x;`

Comment: The rule is simple. `const` goes _after_ the type that should be constant. As a special case, `const` at the beginning applies to the innermost type.

Comment: Jan, thanks, but can you explain what do you mean by "innermost type"?

Comment: as a side note : be careful with dynamically allocating memory inside a constructor for raw pointers. It's not exception safe, and can lead to memory leaks or worse. Always use smart pointers for this purpose, and keep a general eye out for exception safety issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not a `const` pointer, but a pointer to `const`. So you can modify the pointer, you can't that which it points to.

A `const` pointer is

```
int* const x;
```

and your code wouldn't compile then.